# Have to register every class before the autofac container can resolve?

Tags: autofac

let's say this scenario:

```
public class B {};

public class C
{
     public C(B b){}
}
```

To resolve C from Autofac container, I have to register both B and C to container.
But, today I used [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/), it seems I just need to register B to container, then C can be resolved.

So Autofac can't do as Unity do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With out-of-the-box Autofac it is expected that every type you want to use is registered with the container, either directly using the `Register...` methods or in bulk using `RegisterAssemblyTypes`. But there are other options too, take a look at [Nicholas article about resolving everything](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/resolve-anything/). So yes, Autofac can do what Unity does, but you'll have to enable it.

**Update:** actually, the "resolve anything" feature is built-in now, and you can do the following:

```
        var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
        cb.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
        return cb.Build();
```

With the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` you can actually resolve both `C` and `B` without registering any of them.

Note that the lifetime of services resolved by `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` will be ["per dependency scope"](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope).

**Note:** [this topic](http://groups.google.com/group/autofac/browse_thread/thread/8140a17734bf217d#) over at the Autofac discussion group is related.

Comment: What's the default lifetime of the AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource

Comment: @JJS - that would be the Autofac-in-general default lifetime, which is "per dependency scope" (ref https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope)